# error using memmap to parse header in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, enthought

Here is the code that i am trying to enforce with real example

```
#Create a dtype to represent the header.
header_dtype = dtype([('rows', int32), ('cols', int32)])
# Create a memory mapped array using this dtype. Note the shape is empty.
header = memmap(file_name, mode='r', dtype=header_dtype, shape=())
# Read the row and column sizes from using this structured array.
rows = header['rows']
cols = header['cols']
# Create a memory map to the data segment, using rows, cols for shape
# information and the header size to determine the correct offset.
data = memmap(file_name, mode='r+', dtype=float64,shape=(rows, cols),  
offset=header_dtype.itemsize)
```

The file format that i want to read using memmap is

[image]

I am wondering what is going wrong when i try to read the following file named matrix.dat

```
4 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I am doing the following in python (Enthought's canopy editor)

```
header_dtype = dtype([('rows',int),('cols',int)])
header=memmap('matrix.dat',mode='r',dtype=header_dtype,shape=())
rows = header['rows']
cols=header['cols']
print header
(221519924, 840970506)

print rows cols
221519924, 840970506
```

Why i am not getting 4, 4? How do i change the file matrix.dat shown above to read the data correctly?

Comment: The file is understood as binary, so the first 4 bytes will be 0x3420340d, which translates to 221519924. You probably have to write the values in binary mode in the file.

Comment: @YolandaRuiz You should post that as an answer. With the addition that `numpy.loadtxt` if better suited for text files.

Answer (score 1):

The file is understood as binary, so the first 4 bytes will be `0x3420340d`, which translates to 221519924. You probably have to write the values in binary mode in the file.

For text files, use `numpy.loadtxt` instead;

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: cat matrix.dat
4 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16

In [3]: np.loadtxt('matrix.dat')
Out[3]: 
array([[  4.,   4.],
       [  1.,   2.],
       [  5.,   6.],
       [  9.,  10.],
       [ 13.,  14.]])
```

Comment: Yolanda! thanks for your answer. I am looking for solution using memmap. Let me put the complete code so that you get to know every thing.